# Log user detail who restarted a service

Tags: linux, python

This is related to a question asked by me some time back.

I want to log the details regarding who restarted a particular service on Linux.

For example:

If a user X restarts apache, then it would log username, time, service (i.e apache) and status(success/fail).

I can do this writing a small script and adding it manually to the service startup script.

But this would be not possible because i have thousands of servers and tens of services.

Is there any other way i can do this without manipulating the service startup script?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest locking down the system. Require the user to use `sudo`, only allow specific commands to be executed using `sudo`, and disallow running arbitrary commands by banning things like `sudo su` and `sudo bash`.

`sudo` will log all commands executed through it, including, of course, service restarts. On my machine it logs to `/var/log/secure`, which is only readable by `root`.

However, that doesn't give you the last thing you wanted - success or failure. But you could easily implement that extra logging with a wrapper script, which you could require the user to use instead of starting the service directly - just be careful to make the wrapper script secure!

So the user would type:

```
sudo wrapper_script start service
```

or something like that.

Note that sudo logs *both* the original user and the user they are sudo-ing as (by default, root).